# How to create object field in api-blueprint?

Tags: java, apiblueprint

I am trying to document POST request with one object field and one predefined. How can I do it properly? This solution breaks the Schema after api-blueprint parsing.

```
### Create order [POST]

Create a new order

+ Request Post new patient (application/json)

    + Attributes (object)

        ### CustomIds 
            + system: `['Some1', 'Some2']` (string, optional) - The order custom id's system
            + Members
                + `Test1`
                + `Test2`
                + `Test3`
        + customerName: `John` (string, required) - The customer's given name
        + customIds: `some, 123` (array[CustomIds], optional) - custom ids
    + Body

            {
                "customerName" : "John", 
                "customIds": [{"system": "some", "id": "123"}] //optional
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
### Create order [POST]

Create a new order

+ Request Post new order (application/json)

    + Attributes (object)
        + customIds (object)
            + id: `12345` (string, optional) - The order custom id
            + system: `Some` (enum[string], optional) - The order custom id's system name
                + Members
                    + `Some1`
                    + `Some2`
                    + `Some3`
        + customerName: `John` (string, required) - The customer's given name
    + Body

            {
                "customerName" : "John", 
                "customIds": [{"system": "some", "id": "123"}] //optional
            }
```